# How to restart a terminated workflow?

Tags: workflow, odoo

In a model with a workflow, when you create a new record it starts a new `workflow instance`. It will then transition between "activities" until it reaches a `flow stop`, typically a `cancel` or `done` state.

What I'm experiencing in OpenERP 6.1, is that once a `workflow instance` reaches the `flow stop`, it's dead and you cannot perform more transitions on it.

But I would like to have a `Reset to draft` button on a form that would allow a terminated workflow to be restarted. Is there a way to achieve this, say, through a Python call to a method of the Openerp workflow services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find an example at account payment module.

```
def set_to_draft(self, cr, uid, ids, *args):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'draft'})
    wf_service = netsvc.LocalService("workflow")
    for id in ids:
        wf_service.trg_create(uid, 'your.model.name', id, cr)
    return True
```

Comment: I used this. Just needs to also `import netsvc`.

Comment: I believe you should delete the workflow instance as in `purchase.order`. I checked the `workflow_service.trg_create` which calls `instance.create` and none of them delete the old instance before adding the new one.

Comment: I considered deleting, but I think I prefer to keep in the history that the workflow was reset.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the workflow instance and recreate it. Check the method `action_cancel_draft` in the `purchase.order` model; It does exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Good to know. For future reference, the delete instruction is similar to trg_create(): `wf_service.trg_delete(uid, 'purchase.order', p_id, cr)?`.

Comment: @Ruchir Shukla, I wonder why someone downvotes an answer without a comment! I really want to now what is wrong with my answer.